# Performing a method on an int

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors, int

I am trying to generate a random number for an int through a method. I know that this cannot be done because an int is a primitive type and I get an int cannot be deferenced error. Is there is away around it to where I can still use the method to get the value for the int?

---

```
public int move()
 {
     Random random = new Random();
     int generatedNum = random.nextInt(7 - 1) + 1;

     return generatedNum;
 }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int player1 = 0;
    int player2 = 0;

    player1 = player1.move();
    player2 = player2.move();

}
```

Comment: Sorry, don't get your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to do?
 This would work, but no idea if it is what you want...

```
// made this static so you don't need a class reference
public static int move()
 {
     Random random = new Random();
     int generatedNum = random.nextInt(7 - 1) + 1;

     return generatedNum;
 }

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int player1 = 0;
    int player2 = 0;

    // Now we just call the static method move to set the ints.
    player1 = move();
    player2 = move();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

int is a primitive type and Integer is final, so no, you will never be able to write 5.move().
You could write a class that just wraps an integer, but will not be able to do arithmetics with it.

Maybe `Iterator<Integer>` is an interface worth implementing.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own class similar to the Integer class (which is unfortunately `final` or you'd be able to subclass that).  Then add whatever methods you'd like to that class.  A little inconvenient to use when you want to retrieve the value, but not too messy.

Comment: Which is fortunately final, thus enforcing immutability.

Comment: @MouseEvent - Depends on how you look at it.  There are other ways to crack that nut.